# text input value is not going back to 0

Tags: jquery

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/2/ I am having a problem with a text input value being displayed.

What should happen is that if the Option is `True or False` or `Yes or No`, then the Number of Answers text input should always contain the value 1 (ALWAYS, this value can't change); if the user then changes from `True or False` or `Yes or No` option to one of the numbered options, then the text input should go back to 0.

The problem though if the user appends the `True or False` or `Yes or No` option into a table row, does not turn on any of the answer buttons of either `True`,`False`,`Yes` or `No` and then changes the option to one of the numbered options, then instead of displaying 0, it is still displaying value 1.

But if the user does turn on one of either `True`,`False`,`Yes` or `No` answer buttons and then change the option from `True or False` or `Yes or No` to one of the numbered options, then it does change the value in text input from `1` to `0`.

Why is it doing this and how can it be fixed so that everytime a numbered option is selected, it is always going to be `0` in the text input?

I believe the problem is somewhere below but not sure:

```
$(this).closest('.option').siblings('.answer').find('.answers').each(function(index) {
    if (!isNaN(clickedNumber) && index < clickedNumber) {
      $(this).show();
      if (prevButton === 'True or False' || prevButton === 'Yes or No') {
        // show as blank
        $(this).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').val(0).show();
      } else {
        // show but don't change the value
        $(this).closest('.option').siblings('.numberAnswer').find('.answertxt').show();
      }
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
      $(this).removeClass('answerBtnsOn');
      $(this).addClass('answerBtnsOff');
    }
    ....

    function btnclick(btn, iQuestionIndex, bDisableAppend) {
      //var context = $(btn).parent();
      var context = $(btn).parents('tr'); // need to go up one level
      context.add(context.siblings()); // to collect siblings in other rows since the limit in each row is 7
      if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
      }
      var $btn = $(btn);
      var value = btn.value;
      var id = $btn.attr('id');
      ....
      updateAnswer(context , iQuestionIndex, bDisableAppend);
      var container = $btn.closest(".optionAndAnswer");
      // here the zero gets assigned
      var answertxt = $(".answertxt", container);
      var numberison = $(".answerBtnsOn", container).length;
      var maxRowValue = $('.gridTxt', container).val();
      if (btn.id == "answerTrueRow" || btn.id == "answerFalseRow")
        return;
      if (maxRowValue === 'True or False' || maxRowValue === 'Yes or No') {
        if (answertxt.val() == 1 && numberison == 0) {
          numberison = 1;
        }
      }
      answertxt.val(numberison);
      return false;
    }
```

UPDATE:

The fiddle is just a complete shortened version of the main application. For each row appended it counts as a question, so row 1 is question 1, row 2 is question 2 etc. In the fiddle you selct an option type, number of answers and correct answers in the top and then append it into a row. You can edit an option type, number of answers, and correct answers in an appended row if you wish if you want to make a change. That is why it is set out as the way it is set out.

STEPS TO FOLLOW FOR JSFIDDLE:

Steps to see what happens if previous option is `True or False` or `Yes or No` but no answer button is turned on:

1. When you open the app, click on the `Open Grid` link and select the button `True or False` or `Yes or No` from the grid. Then click on the `Add Question` button, this will append a row underneath of what you have selected.
2. You can see in the text input in the appended row that the value for Number of answers is 1, this is fine. But in the appended row click on `Open Grid` and select a number option of either 3 or 4. The text input for Number of answers does not change to 0 as it should do, it still displays 1.

Steps to see what happens if previous option is `True or False` or `Yes or No` but an answer button is turned on:

1. Repeat step 1 from the above.
2. Repeat step 2 from the above but before you click on `Open Grid` to change the option, select the `Answer` button at the bottom of the row of either `True` or `False` / `Yes` or `No` (depends which option you chose) then change the option to a number option. You see that the value does change from 1 to 0.

UPDATE:

I have had a working fiddle here with my old code: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/50/

Here is latest jsfiddle which isn't quite working: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/53/

I have found that the only difference between the fiddle and what has stopped it working is this code below:

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
var $td = $("<td width='50%' class='extratd'>");
var $options = $("<table class='option'><tbody><tr><td>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $noofanswers = $("<br /><table class='noofanswers'><tbody><tr><td>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $answer = $("<br /><table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $questionType = '';
```

The working version contains the code below:

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
var $noofanswers = $("<div class='noofanswers'>2. Number of Answers:<br/></div>");
var $options = $("<div class='option'>1. Option Type:<br/></div>");
var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");
var $questionType = '';
```

If I change the `$options`, `$noofanswers` and `$answer` variable from `<table>` tags to `<div>` tags, then it works. But I want the variables to be placed in `<table>` tags not `<div>` tags. So how come it doesn't work when in `<table>` tags?

Comment: (offtopic) you're still on that project? it's been a year ;)

Comment: @roXon  I asked same thing a few days ago... is some sort of course material which is why same UI shows up over and over again with all sorts of different code approaches

Comment: Could be. But that material... I sound evil, but seeing that software, for the 10th time, I still don't understand how to use it and what's for. Usually Answerers can help you if you stick-To-The-Issue, instead of throwing us a bunch of code with hardly understandable U.Interface and question-descriptions.

Comment: @roXon agree..I cringe also every time I see this ...seems like every time this shows up... questions are non specific

Comment: @user1930247   educate us where this material comes from, a link would help. Understanding starting point would help since this UI shows up so often

Comment: @roXon Yeah deadline in january, just going through testing but realised this little silly problem

Comment: @DavidThomas I will delete the other question, forgot to delete that other question.

Comment: @ATOzTOA i have included series of steps on how to use the fiddle to see what is happening

Comment: @charlietfl I have included update on reason for the UI I have and steps to follow jsfiddle

Comment: @user1930247 WHat I am really curious about is where this exercise comes from. It shows up here all the time. Would really help if these demo had better visual CSS

Comment: I have updated the jsFiddle with indentation for HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/3/

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I know what you mean. To be honest there is teo of us working on this project. I am doing functionality (back end) but I am more of an SQL/oracle developer than a web developer, this year is first time I have used jquery. The other people is doing the front end and is designing the page but he has had health problems and would not start till january, but his deadline is in August while mine is January.

Comment: @user1930247 if this is a continuation of the same project, and not as I assumed a learning exercise....best approach would be scrap the whole thing and get someone who understands the DOm and javascript to do it properly from the beginning. The code, and css in this module is terrible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NhaCN/

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
var $td = $("<td width='50%' class='extratd'>");
var $options = $("<table class='option'><tbody><tr><td>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $noofanswers = $("<br /><table class='noofanswers'><tbody><tr><td>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $answer = $("<br /><table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $questionType = '';
```

You are creating a jquery element with two tags, a `br` and a `table`. So, whatever you append to the element will get added to both the tags.

**Working code**

```
var $tbody = $('#qandatbl_onthefly > tbody');
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
var $td = $("<td width='50%' class='extratd'>");
var $options = $("<table class='option'><tbody><tr><td>1. Option Type:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $noofanswers = $("<table class='noofanswers'><tbody><tr><td>2. Number of Answers:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $answer = $("<table class='answer'><tbody><tr><td>3. Answer:</td></tr></tbody></table>");
var $questionType = '';
```

If you need new line between the elements, then add it here:

```
$tr.append($td);
$td.append($options);
$td.append("<br/>");
$td.append($noofanswers);
$td.append("<br/>");
$td.append($answer);
$tbody.append($tr);
```

Comment: So will I need to create a new function in order to do this? I upvoted your answer. If you know how to fix it then please post your answer as I believe you will have more of an idea of being able to fix this. I will try and give it a go fixing it as well obviously

Comment: I am trying for the past couple hours to figure out your cryptic code. It seems the issue is with adding and removing the "answerBtnsOn" class.

Comment: Updated answer with more clarification.

Comment: I know its difficult, I tried for days trying to figure it out. I know before I had this problem I actually had a working version but even though I believe I haven't changed jquery code, it is suddenly causing this problem. Here is the fiddle where it was working: http://jsfiddle.net/7sARw/27/. I am just trying to see where the difference is

Comment: Found the solution, updated answer...

Comment: I just included an update to my question stating that I know where problem is but I have just seen your answer where you have found it in same place. Thank you very much :) SO if I want to include a break tag which I want to do, then how and where is best place to include break tags as I want a break after each table?

Comment: @ATOzTOA I came back here just to see if there were any heroes. Wow. +1. This one deserves an Oscar.

Comment: @roXon I got bald trying to figure it out... spent like 4 hours... :)